# mac OSX 10.15.1 cannot remove system root certificate

Tags: macos, certificate, system

my mac 10.15.1 cannot remove system root certificate, could anyone please help?

I could not delete the cert nor change the `read-only` state of the keychain file.

Steps:

RecoveryModeTerminal:

```
csrutil disable
```

NormalLoginTerminal:

```
su
security delete-certificate -c "SomeExpiredCert" /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertifictes.keychain
```

Response:

```
security: SecKeychainItemDelete: UNIX[Read-only file system]
```

NormalLoginTerminal:

```
chmod -R 777 /System/Library/Keychains
```

Response:

```
chmod: Unable to chage file mode on /System/Library/Keychains: Read-only file system
chmod: Unable to chage file mode on /System/Library/Keychains/EVRoots.plist: Read-only file system
chmod: Unable to chage file mode on /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain: Read-only file system
chmod: Unable to chage file mode on /System/Library/Keychains/SystemTrustSettings.plist: Read-only file system
```